# how to set height and width of an iframe

Tags: javascript

how can we set the outer iframe inline style( height and width) using an external javascript?

I define the outer frame inside a domain, and the the child frame inside another domain using  an external javascript and append to the outer frame.Then I tried to make my outer frame with the width and height of the inner frame.But it shows some cross domain problem.How can we retify this problem using javascript?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle so that we can look into your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way we solved it where I work is by using [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) to communicate the desired height from within the iFrame to the parent when the iFrame had finished loading its content. That way the inner child can control the size of the parent without being allowed to execute arbitrary code on the parent document.